Type-hinting and preventing import-recursion between python modules
I have two modules with classes, and I want to have accessible functions to convert between their forms. Here's a simpler 'one way' example, where A can be passed to the constructor of B, or the method A.to_B can be used to perform the same construction from an instance of A. In more complex examples, neither class would be used in the constructor, but both would have to_B and to_A methods respectively. Either way, both modules need references to each other, and typing hints.
I'm trying to figure out how to use annotations, particularly the typing module so that there are not circular imports, but I can also clearly document for package users and type hint (particularly for ipython). I feel I'm close, but can't quite put my finger on the best practice so thought I'd better ask for some help.
a.py
class A:
    #...

    def to_B(self) -> B:
        #...
        return B(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    b = a.to_B()
    print(b.a())

b.py
from a import A
class B:
    def __init__(self, a: A) -> None:
        self._a = a # Store reference
        # Use properties of `a` as a spec for generating B attributes
        # ...
        return

    def a(self) -> A:
        return self._a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    b = B(a)
    print(b.a())

In the above code, calling B in A.to_B and throws a NameError, both for the return call as well as the annotation. So instead, I can use an inline import and modify the return reference (i.e. a Forward Reference as specified in PEP563) for to_B(self), which compiles and runs without a hitch. The changes are to a.py are as such:
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from b import B

#... 
class A:
    # ...
    def to_B(self) -> "B":
        from b import B
        # ...
        return B(self)

Should I alternatively be conditionally importing by checking locals() inside to_B at runtime, rather than always import B inside to_B? I feel like I'm breaking python golden rules by importing away from the header of the .py files haha.
Is this the best way to provide hint typing between linked modules, while also preventing module import recursion?

Questions regarding "the best way" to do something are generally not suitable for SO. The topic of avoiding import loops for the purposes of type hinting has already been asked multiple times before. Does this question have anything new that are not covered by Python type hinting without cyclic imports's multiple answers?

This question is similar to: How to avoid circular dependency caused by type hinting of pointer attributes in python. (retracted VTC, just linking to common approaches)

And please don't "conditionally import by checking locals()" - I'm not sure what you mean, but python imports are "cached" in sys.modules, so importing the same thing several times is a no-op, import is idempotent.

@InSync Thanks for the link. The only unique difference is use and hinting between classes, i.e. it's not just hinting. Though usage is a problem older than hinting, so this question probably is redundant.
@STerliakov I meant you can check if not "A" in locals(): followed by from a import A - I thought this may be a way of getting around circular imports - though this seems silly now as why would it ever be defined in the namespace. Thanks for teaching me the word idempotent!

The issue you are facing is that the two modules and classes are highly coupled.  A tightly depends on B and vice-versa.  Generally this is an indicator of hard to maintain code.  You also have low code cohesion: the classes A and B are responsible for not only handling their own behavior, but also for handling the conversion to the other class.
One option is to separate the conversion process from classes into specific conversion functions or classes.
# --------------------------------------------------
### a.py
class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
        ...

# --------------------------------------------------
### b.py
from a import A

class B:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z) -> None:
        ...
    @classmethod:
    def from_a(cls, a: A):
        # create from a's properties

# --------------------------------------------------
### converters.py
import a
import b

def convert_a_to_b(a_obj: a.A, b_obj: b.B):
    ...

